# index of a word changed after the array was converted to lower case, and saved as a new list

Tags: arrays, indexof

so I converted my array to lower case using HashSet, and saved it to a new Array, However, this changed the index of words, and now my dialog box description of an item and a webpage that has to load on itemClick are all off. please, help!
Ihad to convert caps as i needed to get the exact corresponding data for the item on click. Thanks in advance!

Comment: HashSet doesn't assure the order of elements to be preserved. Why do you have to use HashSet?

Answer (score 0):

If the language you're using is Java, you can simply use [toLowerCase](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-tolowercase) method. Try using this.

Comment: oh, i didn't know that HashSet does not preserve the original position of strings. thanks! trying to work out the toLowerCase method as easily as possible...

Answer (score 0):

tried many different ways! but found this code from the post from 2010!! and it worked like a charm!!!!
      `public static void replace(List strings){
          ListIterator iterator = strings.listIterator();
          while (iterator.hasNext())
          {
           iterator.set(iterator.next().toLowerCase());
         }
         }
thank you, Mathew from 2010!!!